# Architecture for Java, Android, Database Application? what should the app look like

Tags: java, javascript, android

I have a site where, via Android, a user needs to:

1. fill in a document (simple html I think).
2. the next step would be to sign on the Android.
3. the data should be saved into a database inside the site.

Points I should mention:

- the UI should be as simple as it gets
- I am the one who should build the web database

So therefore my idea was :

1. the application would open an browser where the user will insert all his stuff into the html.
2. the html will save automatically all the data into a class called data.
3. the next intent of the application would be the surfaceView (where like a painter the user will sign).
4. the surfaceView will be saved into png and with data both will be stored in another class which will be inserted into the server.
   so in this class would be two files the png one and one contain all the info that was on the html as strings (Jonathan Leffler  I hope this one solves my misleading)
5. the server will take this class and parse it and save it into tables.

Someone has another idea?

In which language should I write it? I thought Java and Android where the database would be MySQL.  Does anyone have another idea?

another idea I have is to change this html file into Android sheet
so all the information would be stored on the device and by clicking upload all the information would be sent to the internet site where a server will store it in his database

Can someone point what would be a better solution

note:in my second solution no internet availability is needed so it can work offline where in the first case its needed.

I would like to hear more then on solution on to pick the best who fits my qualities

Comment: If, as seems to be the case, you are proposing to transfer the data from the form to the database via a PNG image file, then you are definitely not on the right track.  Especially if the DBMS has to analyze the PNG to extract the data - OCR in a DBMS is not impossible, but it is not standard.  I hope I'm misunderstanding your proposal!

Comment: so i would like to know what i should do (this is the reason this question is here hearing others and taking the simplest offer )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a webpage optimized for mobile display for Android. That should be PHP and MySQL.

The next thing would be a native Android application written in Java. That will probably use some local data, so it will use mobile SQLite database on the phone.

When the user logs into your website, that is done by the web, and later it will redirect the user to a custom scheme something like `signature://capture` . The webview will detect this scheme, and will launch your native app.

You will setup your Android application to react to this custom scheme, so it will open up, and will open up the SurfaceView. Then the user will be able to touch the screen, to give his signature.

When you capture the signature, either the set of the points (reccomended) or the generated image (will cause postprocessing issues) you will issue a simple HTTP Post method, that will send/post the data to your server.

So you will end up having in your web environment the captured signature.

Good luck with development.

Comment: can you wrie it sown into steps please where you write what are the optiones the write those steps (1.i dont know php ? is it simple php that one can learn in few days ? 2.about the android part can you explain what i should do there i didnt get it '3. do you have a link explaning the all signutre stuff)
lots of thanks man.

Comment: It's too much trouble to explain each step more detailed. If you don't know PHP, do in some other language you are familiar with. And for whatever other major/minor question you have, create a brand new question for it, for each of the problem, even if you end up with 300 questions. It will worth.

Comment: Saying that PHP & MySQL would provide a "website optimized for mobile display for Android" is like saying "you need a car, so use a Yugo." Any server side programming language can provide this capability.